# How to strip time stamps from a file?

Tags: bash, sed, awk

I have log which contains lines of data:

```
Mon Apr 20 03:15:18 EDT 2015: my|data|data|data
```

I am trying to write a script which would extract just the data from
the log, stripping the leading time stamps:

```
while read p
do
   echo $p | sed "s/.* EDT $year: //g" > replay_message_$count.txt;
   count=$((count+1));
done < $fileName
```

Right now I am using the pattern `.* EDT $year:`, where `$year` is a
parameter passed by the user.

What would be a way of extracting the data without having to pass the year as parameter?

Answer (score 2):

If you know that the date format will always have six space-separated fields, you could use:

```
cut -d ' ' -f 7-
```

If you know that your time stamp always occupies 30 characters, you
can use:

```
cut -c 31-
```

If you know that your time stamps end with a digit, followed by a
colon, followed by a space, and that your data does not include this
pattern, you can use:

```
sed 's/.*[0-9]: //'
```

If you have more specific requirements, you're welcome to mention them.

Answer (score 0):

This is intended to replace all of the `while` loop in your script:

```
awk '{print substr($0, 31)>("replay_message_" NR-1 ".txt")}' file
```

How it works:

- `print substr($0, 31)`

  This prints all but the first thirty characters of the line.
- `>("replay_message_" NR-1 ".txt")`

  This sends what was printed to a file named after the line number.

When the awk command is finished running, there will be a series of files in your directory like:

```
$ ls -1 replay_message*
replay_message_0.txt
replay_message_1.txt
replay_message_2.txt
replay_message_3.txt
```

### Alternative in case the length of the timestamp varies

```
awk '{sub(/.* E[SD]T [[:digit:]]{4}: /, ""); print >("replay_message_" count++ ".txt")}' file
```

**How it works**

awk implicitly reads a file one record (line) at a time.  For each line:

- `sub(/.* EDT [[:digit:]]{4}: /, "")`

  This removes the timestamp from the beginning of the line.

  The regex matches everything up to a space, the timezone (either EST or EDT), a space, four digits for the year, a colon, and a space.

  Alternatively, if it were guaranteed that your timestamp only takes 30 characters, then a simpler substitution could be used:

  ```
  sub(/.{30}/, "")
  ```

  Based on your input files, you will have to decide what best fits your situation.
- `print >("replay_message_" count++ ".txt")`

  This writes the modified line to a file which includes a `count` number.  The `++` causes the `count` to be incremented with each write.

Comment: Some remarks: You can just use the input field separator `FS` (or `-F` switch) to split the lines into two pieces. Instead of introducing the variable `count` you can use the input record number `FNR`. This would reduce it to `awk -F': ' '{ print $2 > "replay_message_"FNR-1".txt" }' file`

Comment: The suggestion to replace `count` with `NR-1` is a good one.  There is a reason why I didn't go with a simpler pattern match: if the `my|data|data|data` part of the line happened to contain one or more `: `, then the `-F': '` solution would lead to silent errors.

Comment: It generates the files. However all the generated files still have the timestamp in the front. I tried both patterns `sub(/.{30}/, "")` & `sub(/.* EDT [[:digit:]]{4}: /, "")` and both didn't work. Any idea?

Comment: @Sas That is strange.  However, please try the new version at the top of the revised answer.  It does not use the `sub` function at all.